# UIScrollview with keyboard : contentOffset issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, autolayout

I want to scroll contents of scrollview and below is the code to do that. Issue is `contentOffset` of scrollview is not changed even if I change it programmatically.

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];

    // If active text field is hidden behind keyboard then scroll it so it's visible.
    CGRect aRect = self.contentView.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    // Change contentInset
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height - TABBAR_HEIGHT, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        // scorll the contentView accoring to which textField is selected.
        CGFloat yvalue = - ((self.scrollView.frame.size.height - ((self.editedRealName.isEditing)? self.editedRealName.frame.origin.y :self.birthdate.frame.origin.y)) - self.scrollView.contentOffset.y - (kbSize.height - TABBAR_HEIGHT)) + 35;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yvalue) animated:YES];
    } completion:nil];   

    // printing contentOffset at this point prints older value.i.e.(0,0).
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    // Here, when print contentOffset value then it prints modified value.

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        //scroll the contentView back to top.
        self.scrollView.ContentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } completion:nil];

}
```

Changing `contentInset` scrolls contents up and textfield is visible. But I want it to scroll 10 points more so that textfield and keyboard has 10 points margin between them. With above code margin between them is 0 points.

I use auto layout. I don't know if there is anything it has to do with my issue.

Comment: Didn't it work to simply increase the bottom-inset of your scrollview by 10?     UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height - TABBAR_HEIGHT + 10, 0.0); - From software engineering point of view there would be some fine adjustment of course required (consider landscape mode etc. where it probably shall be somehow different...)

Comment: @Lepidopteron Increasing `contentInset` bottom by 10 will display scrollview's superview in that 10 point gap between scrollview and keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your textfield is within the uiscrollview... Why do you even scroll the uiscrollview up/change its insets, if the textfield is not within this scrollview?